# javascript navigation buttons (previous next) based on a html unordered list

Tags: php, javascript, html, menu

I've a page called index.php that contains a div list like this:

```
<div id="links">
     <ul>
        <li><a href="example1.php">example1</a></li>
        <li><a href="example2.php">example2</a></li>
        <li><a href="example3.php">example3</a></li>
        ......
        <li><a href="exampleN.php">exampleN</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

that is the list of page of my site, showed in the index.php page. I want to add a "prev | home | next" menu to each page in the site (example1, example2, example3,...,exampleN), where "prev" gets me to the previous example and next to the next example, i.e. if I'm watching example number 3 (page example3.php), prev takes me to example number 2 (page example2.php) etcetera.

I'd like to use a script that is not based on a fixed array (defined by the user), because I do not want to update this array each time a new page is added to the index.php list.

I thought of a function like this: suppose we're in example2.php

```
function blahblah(){
    1) get the link list using DOM from index.php (using an array)
    2) search for "example2.php" in the href value of each element in the list, to get the index of the array: in this case, "example2.php" is the 2nd link of index.php, so the array index will be 1 (i.e. alert(linkList[1].href) will print "example2.php")
    3) once we know the index, previous page index will be "index-1" and next page will be "index+1"
}
```

About getting the list (1st point in my pseudocode), I don't know how to acces other pages (on the same domain) using DOM elements.. does someting like document("page").getElementById('links') exist without the need of an iframe?

I'm on the right track? Or totally wrong? Any help, idea or advice is appreciated. Thanks, best regards

Comment: These links are manually put in? I think i know what you are saying, but what you want to do seems like a nasty hack.

Comment: if you mean those links in the index.php page, yes, I put them in manually.. why a nasty hack? There's a better way to do that?

Comment: there can be, I'm not saying what you want to do is incorrect, but things can come up and unexpected stuff might happen. Instead of creating something from the links, can you do what you have been doing, create an array and then create the menu from that? This way you are still only updating one thing. Or even a file that just lists information in key:value pair format and then parse that.

Comment: also you are using php, so you can load the index file through php, get the menu list, parse it (PHP has a DOM parser), then update the links on the page.

Comment: (sorry for double post.. can't edit after 5 mins)
like this?

---arrayList.js---
    var list = array(
        "example1" : "http://www.site.com/example1.php",
        "example2" : "http://www.site.com/example2.php",
        ...
        "exampleN" : "http://www.site.com/exampleN.php",
    )
------------------

and then load it in each example page? I can also load in the index.php and then use the array to build the list, so I'll really have just one file to edit :D

what do you think? Anyway thanks!

Comment: ill move this to chat, as we still need to find out what you want to do. Once i know what you want, i can better help you.

Comment: well, give it a minute, i up-voted your post so you can get 20 rep and it's saying you only have 18 still.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5322/discussion-between-matt-and-benderr)

Comment: @Bendererr Hey, I was there for a little bit, but I had to go. If you still need some help just post again or let me know.

Comment: @Matt thanks, I solved it somehow (probably not in the nicest way, but it works). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot access other files easily, but if the div list is on each page, then it is very easy to add a navigation

```
window.onload=function() {
  var navLinks = document.getElementById("links").getElementsByTagName('a');
  var loc = location.href;
  var href,html="";
  for (var i=0;i<navLinks.length;i++) {
    href=navLinks[i].href;
    if (loc.indexOf(href)!=-1) {
      if (i==0) html+='prev ';
      else html +='<a href="'+navLinks[i-1].href'">prev</a>' 
      if (i==navLinks.length-1) html+=' next ';
      else html +='<a href="'+navLinks[i+1].href'">next</a>' 
    }
  }
  if (html) document.getElementById("links").appendChild(html);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the div list is only in the index, not in each page.. if I put it on each page, at the time of adding a new example link I've to update every single page ,and that's what I want to avoid

Comment: Include it as a script or ajax the div in